# pyspark: Exception while saving Large dataframes as csv on external storage

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, pyspark, export-to-csv

I have a dataframe with about 4000 entries in a variable `df` in pyspark.
While i am trying to export the data as csv to external storage i getting a weird errors as follow:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 12 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 12.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 21, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows

Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: offset 2124, count 3889, length 4096

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o77.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

My write command is as follows:

```
df.write.csv("data/out", sep="@", mode="overwrite")
```

My data contains `,` in the context so i specify custom separator `@`.

I was able to export csv if i set limit 20. means one file only named `part-00000-683794ef-bc5e-4566-9e2f-89dd55725571-c000.csv`. Also if i use `df.write.json()` done successfully but not in csv.

But when i try to out the full dataFrame it gives error.

Any Idea what might have causing it.

Schema of the DataFrame:

```
root
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c5: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: The problem probably comes from your data (an operation that throws an exception for some row in your data frame). Try `df.count()` and tell me it works

Comment: `df.count()` gives 2374. reduces the size of dataset for faster operation. still no difference in the error

Comment: `df.count()` will work even when there's a problem in your data, do you think you can try `df.collect()` ?

Comment: can you explain? how to use `df.collect()` to save csv. `df.collect()` works as i can print each row in the iterator.

Comment: How to know if there is some problem in data.

Comment: @JugrajSingh I meant to try `df.collect()` in order to see if there's a bad line or something wrong with the data :) not to write to csv.

Comment: `df.collect() works file. how i suppose to file problem in 2000 lines of data

Comment: @JugrajSingh after a little search, I found answers that mentioned there could be a problem with the speculated schema. Can you add the output of `df.printSchema()` and check whether the datatypes are correct? If not, change the schema accordingly. I would also try changing the limit to different values in order to understand more or less where the problem exists within the data.

Comment: I edit the question with the schema of the dataframe. my concern is that though the column datatype is string it contain `,` in it. so when converting to the csv what happened to the commas.

Comment: A quick question, which Java version did you install?

Comment: Java SE Development Kit 9.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 9 is not yet supported in Spark (maybe it will in Spark3). People are encountering a lot of problems usually writing or reading files.

Try installing java 8 instead. Let me know if it worked.
Don't forget to update your java version and setting all the necessary environment variables.

Comment: It did work. I think the number of characters per cell exceeded the some limit in csv as pointed out by **libreoffice**. that's why csv function throwing error. but not in java8